# Git status shows me all parents directory

Tags: git, shell, github, terminal

I'm in a directory where i want to push to Github. git status shows me:

```
 On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

#   ../directory1/
#   ../directory2/
#   ../directory3/
#   ../directory4/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

That directories are one step back of the directory where i'm working.
It didn't show me the changes in the real directory project.
Any idea?

Comment: Seems like there's a `.git` folder in the branch with `directory{1..4}` and not where the actual project is. Is that right? You may have run `git init` in the wrong folder, then.

Answer (score 3):

The root of your repository is one level up from where you're expecting it to be. You may have initialized it in the wrong directory. Navigate to the directory that you want to initialize it in, and then re-init. Erase the inadvertent repository by removing `../.git`